# Count the number of quotes in a string that's not preceded by a backslash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm using the following expression to find the number of occurences of `'` and `"` in a string I don't want the count to include  `\'` or `\"`.

```
$subStr = 'asdf"asdf""a\\"sdf\'asdf\'\'a\\\'sdf';
preg_match_all('/[^\\\\]\'|[^\\\\]\"/', $subStr, $matches);
echo count($matches[0]);
```

I expect it to return 6 but it only returns `4`. I think this is because the strings `""` and `''` are only count once.

This is what `$matches` contain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => f"
            [1] => f"
            [2] => f'
            [3] => f'
        )

)
```

Is there any way I can get the count of `6`? Note that I also need to exclude the `\"` and `\'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why doesn't it work

You can't use a character class to match a character not preceded by another character. This is because a character class (negated or not) *must* still match a character. For example, `[^a]b` does not mean "`b` not preceded by `a`". It means: "a character that's not `a` followed by `b`".

### The Solution

If you want to match a single-quote or double-quote character not preceded by a backslash, then you'll have to use a lookaround expression (a negative lookbehind, specifically).

The regex you're looking for is `(?<!\\\\)[\'"]`.

**Autopsy:**

- `(?<!` - start of the lookbehind expression

  - `\\\\` - match a literal backslash character
- `)` - end of the lookbehind expression
- `[\'"]` - character class that matches a single character from the list `"'`

**Visual Representation:**

[image: Visual Representation of the regex]

This effectively matches any single-quote / double-quote character that is **not** preceded by a literal backslash character.

Using the above expression with `preg_match_all` is simple:

```
$subStr = 'asdf"asdf""a\\"sdf\'asdf\'\'a\\\'sdf';
preg_match_all('/(?<!\\\\)[\'"]/', $subStr, $matches);
echo count($matches[0]); // => 6
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/107117)

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/([\'"])/', $subStr, $matches);
```

Alternately:

```
print count(preg_split('/[\'"]/', $subStr)) - 1;
```

Update: if you want to escape `\'` or `\"`

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\\\)([\'"])/', $subStr, $matches);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm try to to exclude the \' and \" so if I use this code it will return 8

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, go for a non-regex approach too:

```
$number = substr_count($string, '"') + substr_count($string, "'");
```

Comment: Hi, I want to exclude the \' and \" so if this in the string the ' and " will not count. that's why I use the reg for

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
$subStr = 'asdf"asdf""asdf\'asdf\'\'asdf';
preg_match_all('/["\']/', $subStr, $matches);
echo count($matches[0]);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/107064)